# how to show page loading spinner in jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, load, spinner

How to show a page loading spinner in html page inside page content like  if i move to another page,the loading spinner will show in page content using jquerymobile

Answer (score 1):

Here you go **demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/DfFxp/  **OR** this: http://jsfiddle.net/5r7Q7/

**Jquery code**

```
(
function(a,b,c){setInterval(function(){for(b=0;b<8;c||(a.innerHTML+='<b><i>•'),a.childNodes[b].className='b'+b+' o'+(++b-~c)%8);c=-~c},99)}
)(document.getElementById('spinner'));
​
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="spinner"></div>
</body>​
```

PS - this might help as well but again you can put this in between the page load and the page this gets trigger from : http://jsfiddle.net/N7Z9e/95/ I reckon rest you know more about your app anyways :),